# Any idea why Collections.sort() is not working in the below program?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve a question on Leetcode that is related to Vertical traversal of a binary tree and I have written the below code.
Here Collections.sort() is not working and I am unable to understand why. need some pointers in fixing this code/

```
class Solution {
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>>map = new TreeMap<>();
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> verticalTraversal(TreeNode root)  {
        if(root == null)
            return null;
        rec(0,root);
        for(Integer i : map.keySet())
        {
            result.add((map.get(i)));
        }
        return result;

    }
    public void rec(int pos, TreeNode node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;
        List<Integer>list = map.get(pos);
        if(list == null)
        {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(node.val);
            Collections.sort(list);
            map.put(pos,list);
        }
        else
            list.add(node.val);
        rec(pos-1,node.left);
        rec(pos+1,node.right);
    }
}
```

Input: 
[0,8,1,null,null,3,2,null,4,5,null,null,7,6]

Expected: [[8],[0,3,6],[1,4,5],[2,7]]
Actual: [[8],[0,3,6],[1,4,5],[7,2]]

Comment: You're creating a new (and thus empty) list, then add a single element to the list, then sort this list. Sorting a list with a single element is pointless.

Comment: Maybe because execute only `else`, where is not `Collections.sort`? Have you tried debuging?

Answer (score 0):

You only sort the inner lists once, when you create them. It would make more sense to sort them after adding all the elements.

Remove your current

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

and add

```
for (List<Integer> list : map.values()) {
    Collections.sort(list);
}
```

after you finish adding all the numbers to all the `List`s.

If you need to have the `List`s sorted after each element added (which would be less efficient), you need to sort the `List` every time you add an element.

```
    if(list == null)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(node.val);
        Collections.sort(list);
        map.put(pos,list);
    }
    else
        list.add(node.val);
```

would become

```
    if(list == null)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(node.val); // no need to sort a List with a single element
        map.put(pos,list);
    }
    else {
        list.add(node.val);
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(node.val);
            Collections.sort(list);
            map.put(pos, list);
        }
```

Please try to sort the elements after you add all the elements in the map.